# How to remove whitespaces from field name in SolrNet 3.6?

Tags: solr, solrnet

We are working on ASP.NET MVC3 C# with SolrNet 3.6.
We have used dynamic fields. There are whitespaces in dynamic fields names: e.g Filter_SIM Slots:Single SIM.

How can I remove whitespaces from dynamic field names? (Here Filter_SIM Slots)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whitespace in the field names is because the keys in your Dictionary Object that you have mapped to your dynamic field in your mapping class have spaces in them. If you scrub/parse the key values to remove the whitespaces, your dynamic fields should be corrected as well.